# Bypass proxy for local addresses

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod, proxy

I want to use proxy on my iPhone to be able to access the internet from my organization Wifi, but I face a problem when accessing local intranet addresses (e-mail mainly) as it has to bypass proxy server

how can i configure some addresses to be bypassed?

Comment: system preferences -> network -> wifi-> advanced -> proxy -> bypass addresses